# Im trying to implement queue from clrs book ,but its not working as expected ? whats wrong with my code

Tags: python, data-structures, queue, clrs

I am trying to implement queue from clrs book, but it's not working as expected. What is wrong with my code?

Could it be a problem with queue size or enqueue operation?

However, it is very clear that enqueue operation on queue is not working as expected. Here is my code:

```
class Queue:

    def __init__(self,size):
        self.queue=[None]*(size+1)
        self.tail=1
        self.head=1
        self.size=size

    def enqueue(self,item):
        #error checking 
        if(self.isFull()):
            print("queue overflows,queue full")
            return
        #--------------------
        self.queue[self.tail]=item
        if(self.tail==self.size):
            self.tail=1
        else:
            self.tail=self.tail+1

    def dequeue(self):

        #error checking 
        if(self.isEmpty()):
            print("queue underflows,queue empty")
            return
        #--------------------
        x=self.queue[self.head]
        if(self.head==self.size):
            self.head=1
        else:
            self.head=self.head+1
        return x

    def isFull(self):
        return (self.tail + 1)= self.head

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.head==self.tail

    def first_person(self):
        if(self.isEmpty()):
            return ("queue empty")
        return self.queue[self.head]
```

Answer (score 0):

can you use "==" for comparision, "=" in python is used for assignment.
I assume isFull returns a boolean True or False, depending on the size of the queue, and I also think that it is implemented using circular queue hence this check for tail+1 == head.

```
def isFull(self): 
    return (self.tail + 1)== self.head
```